# How to download fonts from url in android?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I need to download  fonts directly from my android studio project from url https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf. And downloaded fonts should be in my studio projects under fonts directory.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: and what is the problem? can't you click the link and download the file?

Comment: yes, I wanted to do I  I can get this URL from API .After that, it should be automatically downloaded from URL under fonts directory.so every API Call URL might be differ.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/preview/features/downloadable-fonts.html

Comment: I guess OP is looking for this https://developer.android.com/preview/features/downloadable-fonts.html

Comment: ok thnk u all let me try

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38167538/3983054

Comment: yes exactly need this only will try tnks

Answer (score 1):

Download font file from Github after that follow these steps.

```
Go to the (project folder)
Then app>src>main
Create folder assets>fonts into the main folder.
Put your Roboto-Regular.ttf into the fonts folder.
```

Comment: Normally we are done in this way but I need by using URL it has to be downloaded automatically and should save under fonts directly URL might be dynamic URL.

Comment: I know that it can be done through flutter, but don't know any way for android