# How to Add Font Family in react native at once like web

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation-v5

> I want to add font family like i added `{DarkTheme}` that applies on my whole
> app. Otherwise, i have to add my custom font family in every Text component or through stylesheet, where instead i want to make default font family for Text component.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyContextprovider>
      <NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme}>
        <UserSwitchstack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </MyContextprovider>
  )
 };
```

Comment: You tags are misleading: The question is about styling (CSS).

Comment: Do you use styled-components https://styled-components.com/ ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky no it is simple react-native Text Component. i want to add my custom font family at once.

Comment: Did you try to do it with CSS? Where is the problem?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky yes i tried with css but  in react-native is it  possible.... my custom font family default for all  Text component like<Text>MichaelRovinsky </Text>

Comment: You can do it with class: `<Text className="my-class" /> `  and in CSS:  `.my-class { font-family: 'My Font'; }`

Comment: After your Code example, can you "Ask a question" to clarify your need?  Example, How do I ...........  People normally dont like rereading the title to figure out the question.  They usually expect it to all be in paragraph form in the first post.

Comment: @blamb  simple i want to add font family in react-native.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky i think we can do this thing in react js only ..

Comment: @SumitSharma yes, we can. Styled components is a most used and industry standard solution for this.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky can you please give me brief example with react-native that will be very help full for me.

Comment: Please check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383786/6371885

Comment: @KushalDesai yes i saw it and its work fine for me but i want like web where i can just add font-family and it applies on whole web application.

Comment: Now we can use useTheme https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-theme/